# Ask form to perform control update

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Imagine you have FormA and FormB. FormA has a ListBox1 that displays values of DataSource1 (may be a list or array but the bottom line is that it uses ListBox.DataSource assignment). FormB would be instantiated and called by FormA. FormA would modify (add individual rows to list or array, 1 line at the time) DataSource1 that feeds ListBox1 in FormA. How do you ask FormA and its ListBox1 to reload DataSource1 and display new values modified by FormB? Currently FormA passes the whole object that contains source (list or array) to FormB in FormB's constructor. I could pass FormA reference in FormB's constructor and call FormA's methods this way but is it the most efficient way?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had it all wrong. Event handling is the answer. FormA should have a method to reload data source into ListBox1. There should be another method that can be delegated that would take object as sender and EventArgs as e. At formB instantiation appropriate FormB's event handler should receive with sender and event arguments just like you add any delegates. In this case I can use FormClosedEventHandler. Alternatively that method can be delegated to DataSource1.DataSourceChangedEventHandler. And that's it! When event gets triggered, FormA functions as observer and executes its own method through delegate.

Answer (score 2):

i think you need the `observer Pattern` [tutorial](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx)

if it is your first use of Observer you should look at the whole `MVC Pattern`